# Algolia reindex in Magento

Tags: magento, algolia

In my **Magento** I have some modules that do changes to DB manually. For ex., changing some attributes, or importing new products from some catalog etc.

So, **Algolia** hooks not used in this case.

Is there some way to proceed **algolia** reindex from php-script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use magento indexer or magerun (http://magerun.net/) or directly indexer.php with the following commands

`n98-magerun --root-dir=/var/www/htdocs index:reindex algolia_search_indexer`

or

`php -f shell/indexer.php -- -reindex algolia_search_indexer`

Comment: Thx. I do exectly the same, but don't see changes in my product in algolia search.

Comment: Keep in mind that the reindexing is asynchronous (it will take a few seconds/minutes to be actually searchable). But you should see that your indices are building in the Algolia dashboard.

Comment: If you want to reindex from console you should have the Algolia queue disabled. Is it the case ?

Comment: Yep, exactly. Thanks for advice  :)